# How can I have more than three gang members in my vehicle?

Tags: mods, grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

I can have up to seven gang members following me but I can't find any vehicle that allows me to drive more than three of them with me. Can it be done in anyway, be it by finding a vehicle in the game that does the job or a game mod?

Comment: Some vehicles allow more than 3 members. I cannot remember which ones or how many members are allowed or else I'd post as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Bus](http://gta.wikia.com/Bus) and [Coach](http://gta.wikia.com/Coach) can hold 7 passengers.

Comment: Without user mods?